# Would a system ever move a mysql table (storage engine = memory) to swap if system memory consumption goes high?

Tags: mysql

For a system running a mysql table whose storage engine is memory...
when the memory is used up by other tasks and the system begins to use swap space, would it every take the mysql table out of memory?